# Why conditional breakpoint doesn't work in some address in ollydbg?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, ollydbg

I use ollydbg with a 64bit program, in some address the conditional bp work like normal bp,for example

```
LEA RDX,[REL 7FF7_8127B320] 
MOV RCX,QWORD PTR [RSI+3D0]
CALL 00007FF7_80805210
```

inside of 00007FF7_80805210

```
MOV QWORD PTR [RSP+8],RBX
PUSH RDI
SUB RSP,20
MOV RAX,RDX
MOV R11,R9
.
.
.
```

After I set the conditional bp with `R9==5` at `MOV R11,R9`,then it break with `R9 == 10` or other value just like a normal bp.
It happens in the whole address inside the call,but if i set conditional bp at outside like `MOV RCX,QWORD PTR [RSI+3D0]` with `[RSI+3D0]==19DB0258BD0` or `RSI==19D_730D6DB0` it work.

I try `R9 == 00000005` or `R9 == 00000000_00000020` or `R9 == 12345678` and other address inside the call but all fails,the conditional bp all work like a normal bp break when execute to the line.

Comment: The tag says that ollydbg is a **32-bit** debugger, if that is relevant.

Comment: @WeatherVane  The tag says OllyDbg is a Ring3, "Win32" debugger,I think the "32" is just  a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because OllyDbg64 is incomplete/frozen version. Try x64dbg.